# An item jumps to next line on click

Tags: html, css

There is an issue in pagination block, the number item 30 always jumping to next line when clicking on third (bottom) line... [it is here](http://my-mates.rhcloud.com) This happens only in Chrome browser. There is something wrong with css. Could you help me fix it?

Comment: Please use same padding in selected as well or you can use width/height of the elements

Answer (score 1):

All the list items have `padding: 5px`, but when they get selected they get `padding: 2px 4px`.

When you select the `30`, the width of the element is reduced and then it fits next to the `29` on the same row.

Make sure the selected items also get `padding: 5px` so they always stay the same size.

Answer (score 0):

As per Hans Answer, some browsers will alter the padding for li elements when in a :focus state

To fix the problem:

```
li,
li:focus {
 padding:5px;
}
```